# Seeking geographic information for American and world parks and cities?

Tags: data

I am working on building out park data for my web site.  My site is about hiking, so I want to get a list of parks and cities in the world.

Where can I get/download/see such unified information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) provides populated places and park information, and includes both an API and data downloads. This is based on a historical set of global data curated by the US government, but since supplemented by volunteered geographic information.

<strike>[SimpleGeo Places](https://simplegeo.com/products/places/) includes a large number of POIs and is free to use via its API through a nice interface supported in many languages</strike>. SimpleGeo has been shut down, as mentioned in @RyanDalton's comment.

[Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) provides populated places and national parks within the US in shapefile format.

Comment: should I assume that Geonames doesn't have the park data given that they don't list that option here http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html

Comment: It does, most of the data in Geonames is available through the cities and features service, check these export codes under the 'L' group: http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html as used by the search service http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html

Comment: Hi, I have been playing around with that, and I can't seem to get my query right.  I am doing something like http://api.geonames.org/search?maxRows=10&username=demo&q=LAND but that seems wrong.  The LAND argument is for arctic land, but it showed me a place in the carribean :) I am after places where people can hike.  Is there a best set of arguments I can specify? Thanks!

Comment: January 12th, 2012: After SimpleGeo was acquired by Urban Airship in Oct 2011, Urban Aiship said “wind down the availability of the current versions of [SimpleGeo's] Places, Context, and Storage over the next few months.”...The target date for pulling the plug officially will be March 31, 2012. [Link](http://techcrunch.com/2012/01/12/urban-airship-to-shutter-simplegeo-services-in-march-with-factual-picking-up-the-slack/)

Comment: @RyanDalton thanks for the heads-up, I've updated the post to reflect the change.

Answer (score 3):

**Open Street Map**

Recreational (Local) Parks
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:leisure%3Dpark

National Parks
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dnational_park

US National Parks
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/US_National_Park_Service_Data

source is http://www.nps.gov/gis/data_info/

OpenStreetMap (OSM) advantages are it is a free wiki map (including commercial entities can use it for free). Limitation is that data coverage in rural areas can be very limited.