# "Natural Places" data for rivers, lakes, mountains, trails, etc. (everything except city/road/etc. data)

Tags: data

Wondering if there are any data sets for world that describe places like named mountains, rivers, lakes, parks, etc. I know a little of [geonames](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9677/how-to-get-geographic-information-for-american-and-world-parks-and-cities), but it only seems to barely cover the national parks and just high level things. I'm looking for the level of detail found on [Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@47.7727437,-124.305162,15.88z):

[image]

If not, I'd be interested to know how they did that.

Comment: if it is open data that you seek then the place to ask may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of sources from which you can get this data.

You need to look at following links

https://www.gislounge.com/world-gis-data/

Listed here are free sources for finding GIS data in both vector and raster formats including satellite imagery.

Some of the sources include

- Natural Earth World GIS Data
- OpenStreetMap Data
- GeoNames
- Vector Map (VMap)
- USGS EarthExplorer

For your case

**Natural Earth World GIS Data**
https://www.naturalearthdata.com/

This is probably one of the best sources for free global GIS data.
The site was initiated in 2008 by Nathaniel Vaughn Kelso and Tom Patterson and data from the site is coordinated by a group of volunteers.
Good for a global collection of free GIS data. 
Individual layers can be downloaded from Natural Earth for cultural, physical, and raster data at three scales of resolution: 1:10m, 1:50m, and 1:110m.  All of the GIS data offered at Natural Earth is public domain and free to use.